# CONVERTING SQL JOIN TO PYTHON

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, join

```
SELECT *
FROM PlacementDetail_Temp PDT LEFT JOIN    
     dbo.[Authorization] AUTH
     on AUTH.PlacementDetailID = PDT.PlacementDetailID and
        AUTH.PayorID = @PayorID LEFT JOIN
     dbo.Provider SP_as_PR
     on SP_as_PR.ProviderID in
            (Select PR.ProviderID     
             from dbo.Provider PR JOIN
                  dbo.ProviderSponsor PS
                  ON PR.ProviderID = PS.ProviderID and
                     PS.SponsorID = AUTH.SponsorID    
             where IsSponsor = 'True'
            )
```

we have been trying to convert this sql join into  python. but we were not able to do so. stuck up in this **'LEFT JOIN dbo.Provider SP_as_PR on SP_as_PR.ProviderID in'** point

as they are joining using 'in' condition not using 'on' condition

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code conversion service. Please show your efforts

Comment: What does `convert this sql join into python` even mean? Load all data in memory and then try to match items without any benefit of indexing, thus slowing down what is probably already slow? Or use an (unspecified) ORM, in which case joins should be converted to *relations* between entities?

Comment: BTW this query should be fixed. Using an `IN` clause in a JOIN statement is equivalent to a JOIN at best. `dbo.Provider PR` should be removed completely.  `IsSponsor = 'True'` is probably meaningless - SQL Server refuses to index bit columns for a reason. An index with such low granularity is almost meaningless.

Comment: we are converting this join to python.  not able to understand the sql join. can you please explain the sql join